# Problema de envio no formulario de contato tema BigStream Wordpress, configuração do arquivo mail-it.php

Tags: php, wordpress, email, temas

Não estou conseguindo fazer formulário de contato do tema Bigstream do wordpress funcionar, quando clico em enviar ele mostra mensagem de sucesso porém o e-mail não chega.

Achei o seguinte arquivo 'mail-it.php' porem não sei exatamente como configurar, tentei colocar meu e-mail nele mas não adiantou.

Alguém tem ideia de como configurar o e-mail abaixo?

```
<?php

/* Code by David McKeown - craftedbydavid.com */
/* Editable entries are bellow */

$send_to = "meuemail@server.com";
$send_subject = "Ajax form";



/*Be careful when editing below this line */

$f_name = cleanupentries($_POST["name"]);
$f_email = cleanupentries($_POST["email"]);
$f_message = cleanupentries($_POST["message"]);
$from_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$from_browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];


function cleanupentries($entry) {
    $entry = trim($entry);
    $entry = stripslashes($entry);
    $entry = htmlspecialchars($entry);

    return $entry;
}

$message = "This email was submitted on " . date('m-d-Y') .
"\n\nName: " . esc_attr( $f_name ) .
"\n\nE-Mail: " . esc_attr( $f_email ).
"\n\nMessage: \n" . ff_wp_kses( $f_message ) .
"\n\n\nTechnical Details:\n" . esc_attr( $from_ip ) . "\n" . esc_attr( $from_browser );

$send_subject .= " - {$f_name}";

$headers = "From: " . esc_attr( $f_email ) . "\r\n" .
    "Reply-To: " . esc_attr( $f_email ) . "\r\n" .
    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();

if (!$f_email) {
    echo "no email";
    exit;
}else if (!$f_name){
    echo "no name";
    exit;
}else{
    if (filter_var($f_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        mail($send_to, $send_subject, $message, $headers);
        echo "true";
    }else{
        echo "invalid email";
        exit;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Já testou a função mail `<?php if (mail('seuemail@gmail.com', 'teste', 'teste mensagem', 'From: <emailservidor@servidor.com.br>')) echo 'enviou!'; ?>` , para ver se ela está habilitada no seu servidor?

Comment: @IvanFerrer  humm não testei, como faria isso.   Esta hospedado na locaweb ...

Comment: Cria um arquivo enviar.php e executa ele, e coloca os dados na função, igual eu fiz, só que com os dados reais e veja se imprime na tela "enviou" e veja se vc recebeu o email.

Comment: A Locaweb tem alguns padrões, [veja aqui](http://wiki.locaweb.com.br/pt-br/Como_enviar_e-mails_com_a_fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_mail()_do_PHP).

Comment: @IvanFerrer  apareceu enviou mas nao chegou o email ... vou ver esse lance da locaweb ...